# ¿Cómo restar valores de una misma columna?

Tags: r

Quiero restar valores de una misma columna:

```
1  10
2  20
3  5
4  30
5  40
```

Quisiera realizar lo siguiente:

```
10-20= -10;
10-5= 5;
10-30= -20;
10-40= -30;

20-10= 10;
20-5= 15;
20-30= -10
20-40= -20;

5-10= -5;
5-20= -15;
5-30= -25;
5-40= -35;
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda. Voy muy perdido.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Bienvenido Jon Apodaka Saratxo a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Podrías agregar lo que intentaste hasta ahora por favor? Así tu pregunta será mejor recibida y no parecera del tipo "haganme la tarea".

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es generar las combinaciones de cada elemento con el resto, y luego simplemente realizar la resta.

```
x <- c(10, 20, 5, 30, 40)

indices <- 1:length(x)

casos <- subset(expand.grid(indices, indices), Var1 != Var2)
```

Hacemos la combinación de los índices de cada elemento ya que de esta forma es más seguro quitar la combinaciones cuyos índices se repitan. Luego simplemente realizamos la resta, usando los índices como forma de acceder a cada valor:

```
x[casos[[2]]] - x[casos[[1]]]

 [1] -10   5 -20 -30  10  15 -10 -20  -5 -15 -25 -35  20  10  25
[16] -10  30  20  35  10
```

Answer (score 0):

Si conoces lenguajes como Java o C#, tal vez un for loop te ayude a entender el problema. Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
> x <- c(10, 20, 5, 30, 40)
> 
> resultados <- c()
> 
> for(i in 1:length(x)){
+   
+   resultados <- c(resultados, x[i] - x)
+   
+ }
> 
> resultados
 [1]   0 -10   5 -20 -30  10   0  15 -10 -20  -5 -15   0 -25 -35  20  10  25   0 -10  30  20  35  10   0
>
```

Ente este caso resté todos con todos, incluyendo los mismos indices, es decir, el 10 no se restó solamente con el resto del vector, sino consigo mismo también, ya que no se si es esto exactamente lo que buscabas.